# Was there ever a fuel-injected Spitfire?

Tags: aircraft-design, piston-engine, fuel-systems, spitfire

I couldn't find one but did it ever exist? Would adding fuel injection have improved combat effectiveness or fuel efficiency?

Comment: What do you mean "how would it work"? Why would it work different than any other fuel injected motor? These hypothetical questions are difficult to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there was. A Spitfire which was converted by Daimler Benz engineers to use a DB 605 engine. See the following links:

[https://www.klassiker-der-luftfahrt.de/geschichte/flugzeuge/daimler-benz-versuch-die-daimler-spitfire-die-db-spitfire-zeigt-gute-flugeigenschaften/615458?seite=2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320092915/https://www.klassiker-der-luftfahrt.de/geschichte/flugzeuge/daimler-benz-versuch-die-daimler-spitfire-die-db-spitfire-zeigt-gute-flugeigenschaften/615458?seite=2)

[https://defenceoftherealm.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/the-franken-spitfire/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150415054141/https://defenceoftherealm.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/the-franken-spitfire/)

Comment: Both links are dead; this answer would be improved with a little more detail (e.g. when and where)

Comment: The links have been edited to point to the archive.org saved copies of the web pages.

Comment: The Hispano HA-1112 featured a Merlin engine, Hamilton Standard 3 blade, or Rotol 4 bladed propeller on a Me-109 frame.  These flew until the 1960s.

Comment: Updated links are nice, however, including some quotes from the links to support the answer would be even better in case they ever go kaput again. @RobertDiGiovanni, forgive my ignorance, what does that have to do with a fuel-injected Spitfire?

Comment: It's for aviators who know what good is.

Answer (score 3):

> I couldn't find one but did it ever exist?

I do not think so (at least not off the assembly line) the [RR Merlin Engines were Carb'ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Merlin). [The Griffon powered planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Griffon) were also carb'ed however they used an injection carb which is a bit different than a float style carb but not full on fuel injection.

---

> Would adding fuel injection have improved combat effectiveness or fuel
>   efficiency?

Yes, it would have allowed sustained G maneuvers which are not possible in a carbureted plane as the float would fall causing fuel to enter the carb unrestricted.

[As per wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Merlin#Carburettor_developments)...

> However, the Merlin's float controlled carburettor meant that both
>   Spitfires and Hurricanes were unable to pitch nose down into a steep
>   dive.

This was later remedied by installing a [small plate over the float to prevent starvation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermarine_Spitfire_variants:_specifications,_performance_and_armament)

> ...original production variants of the Merlin used an SU manufactured
>   carburettor in which the fuel flow was metered through a float. In
>   most circumstances this proved to be sufficient but during the air
>   battles over Dunkirk and during the Battle of Britain it was found
>   that whenever the Merlin was subjected to negative "g" forces, such as
>   a quick "bunt" into a dive, the engine would briefly lose power
>   through petrol starvation...
>
> ...The remedy, invented by Beatrice "Tilly" Shilling, was to fit a metal 
>   diaphragm with a hole in it, across the float chambers. It partly
>   cured the problem of fuel starvation in a dive. The device was
>   commonly referred to as 'Miss Shilling's Orifice'....

Comment: And then .... the Bendix-Stromberg Pressure Carburettor, circa 1940.